# Using a base class without having an explict cast

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have 2 classes:

```
class MyBase() { }

class A : MyBase() { public int i;}

class B: MyBase() { public int i; }
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
void f(MyBase myBase)
{
    if(myBase.GetType() == typeof(A))
    {
        myBase.i = 1;
    }
    else if (myBase.GetType() == typeof(B))
    {
        myBase.i = 2;
    }
}
```

without having to do:

```
((A)myBase).i = 1;
((B)myBase).i = 2;
```

everytime (of course, assuming that the derived classes of `myBase` always contain `i`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just move `i` into `MyBase` and you're done

Comment: What about implementing a dedicated method?

Comment: But i is not a member of MyBase.  Assume derived classes of myBase always contain i. You are missing the whole concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you "assume that every derived class of `MyBase` must contain `i`" it's a good indication that `i` belongs into `MyBase`. Then your code works already:

```
public class MyBase
{
    public int i;
}
```

or maybe you want to make it overidable in the subclasses, you can force it by making the base class and the property abstract:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
   public abstract int i { get; }
}

public class A : MyBase
{
    public override int i 
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public class B : MyBase
{
    public override int i
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `f` into the derived classes.

```
abstract class MyBase()
{
    public abstract void f();
}

class A : MyBase() 
{ 
    public int i;

    public override void f()
    {
        i=1;
    }
}

class B: MyBase()
{ 
    public int i; 

    public override void f()
    {
        i=2;
    }
}
```

and then call `f` on whatever instance you get...

```
MyBase x = new A();
x.f(); // calls "i=1"
x = new B();
x.f(); // calls "i=2"
```

or, if you like, to keep close to the original syntax:

```
void f(MyBase myBase)
{
    myBase.f(); // calls the one or the other depending on the actual type of myBase
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> of course, assuming that the derived classes of myBase always contain
>   i

I this case, It would be much better to change your class structure and move `i` to the base class.
At least define an abstract member i in your base class so developers know to implement it in their derived classes.

Otherwise you will have constant issues because you forgot to implement i in one of your derived classes and this breaks your whole system.

Having one issue like this is annoying enough, but if you accept this construction here, you will do it elsewhere as well, and your classes will become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score -1):

Set the value of i inside the constructor of each derived class, not outside, as i seems to be a value depending of each specialized type.

```
class A : MyBase() {
public A(){ i = 1;} 
public int i;
}

class B: MyBase() { 
public B(){ i = 2;}
public int i; 
}
```